# How to display only unchecked items in active admin for has many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am using Ruby on Rails 5 with active admin as a backend for resources management. I need to show the only unchecked items for a check_boxes field all the time in new and edit action. Instead of running a complex query for the collection I think this is the best way to manage. All of my associated models stuff related to this are working fine.
[image]

It should show only 2nd item if it is not checked already. 
Right now my code snippet is

```
f.input :subscribers, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Subscriber.all.collect {|subscriber| [subscriber.email, subscriber.id]}
```

Is there any way in active admin to display only unchecked values ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `collection_check_boxes` for this case?

It would look something like this:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:subscribers_ids, Subscriber.all, :id, :email) do |b| %>
  <% if !b.check_box.include?(checked="checked")  %>
    <%= b.label %>
    <%= b.check_box %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I think that should solve your problem. If you want to learn more about [collection_check_boxes](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes)